# jQuery: I need something like ':visible' that works even if the parent is display=none

Tags: jquery

I have a list where elements are hidden for multiple reasons, each corresponding to a css class i.e:

```
<style>
    .filteredOut { display: none; }
    .somethingElse { display : none; }
    ...
</style>
```

I want to apply alternating css classes via `.filter(':even').addClass('even')` but only to classes that are visible.  The problem is that the parent is hidden when this happens so `.filter(':visible')` returns 0 elements.  I need something like `.filter(':visibileEventIfParentIsNot')`

Further more, I'd rather not have to call a function with this in it every time I call a function that changes what's visible in a list.  This may be a pipe dream, but is there a way to do this ala `live()` or something similar?  I'm open to off the wall ideas.

Comment: If the parent display is set to none, then the display isn't even rendered on the html page. I dont think there is any magic way of grabing the parent element if the display is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.filter(':visibileEventIfParentIsNot')` you can write your own filter function, like this:

```
.filter(function() {
   return $(this).css("display") != 'none';
})
```

Note this doesn't cover visibility, just the traditional jQuery cases like `.hide()`, which effectively is the same as `.css('display', 'none')`.

But if you're doing alternating row styles and all the sudden showed an **odd** number of elements, this wouldn't look right, I think you're better off doing the `.filter(':even')` application when the visibility of something changes (maybe the [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event with [`.resize()` plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/)?).

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to control your events.  If you want to filter hidden elements, add the necessary classes to the children.  When they become visible, the browser will reflow the css.